# Add an event in a calendar

Tags: php, mysql, sql, calendar

I solved a few months ago the problem of getting data from two tables and make an event calendar. You can see here:[original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670227/get-data-from-two-tables-to-make-an-event-calendar).
Now I want something more: I want to ad an event for EVERY users in the same time. Let's say is a holiday (like Christmas) and I want to add this event for all users. I am using two queries first is to select the holidays and second to select if user was present. If present tip_id = 0, if not tip_id = 1. Than I put everything in a table. If the day is Saturday or Sunday the color is grey (using css1), if user is present the cell color is white and if user is absent the color is red.
What I need? If I have Holidays in that month, I need the cell color to be also grey (as Saturday and Sunday). I tried different ideas but or I was able to get grey ONLY the first Holiday day, or ONLY the last or I got error when there are NO holidays in that month.
The code (extracted only the part where I need help) is like this:

```
$db_luna=11;
$db_an=2013;
$days_in_month = 31;

mysql_select_db($database_dbconfig, $dbconfig);
$query_Holidays = "SELECT substring(data,9,2) AS zile_sarbatoare, data FROM sarbatori WHERE sarbatori.`data` LIKE '".$db_an."-".$db_luna."-%' ORDER BY zile_sarbatoare";
$Holidays = mysql_query($query_Holidays, $dbconfig) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Holidays = mysql_fetch_assoc($Holidays);
$totalRows_Holidays = mysql_num_rows($Holidays);

mysql_select_db($database_dbconfig, $dbconfig);
$query_Presence = "SELECT c.full_name, c.id_personal, COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN CONCAT($db_an, '-', $db_luna, '-01') BETWEEN start_date AND end_date THEN tip_id END),0) '1', COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN CONCAT($db_an, '-', $db_luna, '-02') BETWEEN start_date AND end_date THEN tip_id END),0) '2', COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN CONCAT($db_an, '-', $db_luna, '-03') BETWEEN start_date AND end_date THEN tip_id END),0) '3', COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN CONCAT($db_an, '-', $db_luna, '-04') BETWEEN start_date AND end_date THEN tip_id END),0) '4', COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN CONCAT($db_an, '-', $db_luna, '-05') BETWEEN start_date AND end_date THEN tip_id END),0) '5' FROM calendar c";
$Presence = mysql_query($query_Presence, $dbconfig) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Presence = mysql_fetch_assoc($Presence);
$totalRows_Presence = mysql_num_rows($Presence);}



<?php do { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $nr_crt, '. ' , $row_Presence['full_name']; ?></td>
                <?php           
                $css1 = 'white';
                $trim = ''; 
                    for ($a = 1; $a <= $days_in_month; $a++){
                        $data_calculata = date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0, $db_luna, $b, $db_an ));
                            if ($row_Presence[$a] == 0) {$legend = $row_Presence['full_name']."".$a;
                                                         $day_of_week = date("N",mktime(0,0,0, $db_luna,$a ,$db_an));
                                                         if ($day_of_week == 6 OR $day_of_week == 7) {$css1 = 'grey';}
                                                         else {$css1 = 'white';}
                            if ($row_Presence[$a] == 1) {$css1 = 'red'; $legend = $row_Presence['full_name']." - Absent";}
                        echo '<td " title= "'.htmlspecialchars($legend).'" class='.$css1.'></td>';
                        $nr_crt = $nr_crt + 1;
                ?>          
        </tr>            
    <?php } while ($row_Presence = mysql_fetch_assoc($Presence)); ?>
  </table>
```

Comment: It is better you specify a type in your event table and set it to "all", instead of entering an entry for each user. While selecting you can get it by a condition something like WHERE type = 'ALL' OR user_id = 10. It is just a suggestion, verify with your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is like this:

```
$db_luna=11;
$db_an=2013;
$days_in_month = 31;

mysql_select_db($database_dbconfig, $dbconfig);
$query_Holidays = "SELECT substring(data,9,2) AS zile_sarbatoare, data FROM sarbatori WHERE sarbatori.`data` LIKE '".$db_an."-".$db_luna."-%' ORDER BY zile_sarbatoare";
$Holidays = mysql_query($query_Holidays, $dbconfig) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows_Holidays = mysql_num_rows($Holidays);
$days_holidays = array();
while ($row_Holidays = mysql_fetch_array($Holidays))
 {
     $days_holidays[] = $row_Holidays['zile_sarbatoare'];
 }
// so, now I have an array with all the days I need

mysql_select_db($database_dbconfig, $dbconfig);
$query_Presence = "SELECT c.full_name, c.id_personal, COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN CONCAT($db_an, '-', $db_luna, '-01') BETWEEN start_date AND end_date THEN tip_id END),0) '1', COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN CONCAT($db_an, '-', $db_luna, '-02') BETWEEN start_date AND end_date THEN tip_id END),0) '2', COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN CONCAT($db_an, '-', $db_luna, '-03') BETWEEN start_date AND end_date THEN tip_id END),0) '3', COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN CONCAT($db_an, '-', $db_luna, '-04') BETWEEN start_date AND end_date THEN tip_id END),0) '4', COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN CONCAT($db_an, '-', $db_luna, '-05') BETWEEN start_date AND end_date THEN tip_id END),0) '5' FROM calendar c";
$Presence = mysql_query($query_Presence, $dbconfig) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Presence = mysql_fetch_assoc($Presence);
$totalRows_Presence = mysql_num_rows($Presence);}



<?php do { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $nr_crt, '. ' , $row_Presence['full_name']; ?></td>
            <?php           
            $css1 = 'white';
            $trim = ''; 
                for ($a = 1; $a <= $days_in_month; $a++){
                    $data_calculata = date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0, $db_luna, $b, $db_an ));
                     if ($row_Presence[$a] == 0) {$legend = $row_Presence['full_name']."".$a;
                                                     $day_of_week = date("N",mktime(0,0,0, $db_luna,$a ,$db_an));
                           $css1 = 'white';                                                         
                        if ($day_of_week == 6 OR $day_of_week == 7) {$css1 = 'grey';}
                        if (in_array($a, $days_holidays)) {$css1 = 'grey';} //here I compare each day if it is in the array
                     if ($row_Presence[$a] == 1) {$css1 = 'red'; $legend = $row_Presence['full_name']." - Absent";}
                    echo '<td " title= "'.htmlspecialchars($legend).'" class='.$css1.'></td>';
                    $nr_crt = $nr_crt + 1;
            ?>          
    </tr>            
<?php } while ($row_Presence = mysql_fetch_assoc($Presence)); ?>
```

For me it is working! The idea to use function "in_array" come from another question from this site. Thank you stackoverflow :)